# problem with issuer certificate in pipeline in bitbucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, github, actionscript

I have a problem... My code is in bitbucket, Pipeline in Jenkins. When I start pipeline I have this error:

> "fatal: unable to access 'fatal: unable to access
> 'https://my.repos.example:***.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable
> to get local issuer certificate"

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write to your verrible GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY = 1 and after that you pipeline download your repo.